# Values are deleting when I Dynamically populate angularjs-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js to create a multi-select drop-down. I'm trying to dynamically populate the drop-down with existing data from mysql database. If I hardcode the array of objects in my scope, the drop-down is populated correctly and select and deselectare working properly. If I pass in the array of objects from the database,  the values are  deleting from the array when I deselect the item any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are You using [this library](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect)??? and also can you plunkr the code for us.

Comment: I am using this code https://jsfiddle.net/michaeldeongreen/22et6sao/9/

Comment: but with dynamic data

Comment: can u show the data recieved from the api.

Comment: Here's an example of adding random data, https://jsfiddle.net/1akmavqb/, without more detail of your own code it's impossible to help.

Comment: this is  my data
[{"label":"P65","id":0},{"label":"D55","id":1}]  , when i click p65 the item is deleting from the json

Answer (score 0):

Try giving different names for `option` and `selected-model`

```
options="example14data" selected-model="example15model"
```

In controller,

```
 $scope.example15model = [];
```

Comment: Yes, I tried adding one more dropdown in your js fiddle it worked.